Can array pointer decay be suppressed or accommodated?
I would like to have a function overload where one use case passes the non-array argument by pointer, and the other use case passes the C-array argument by reference.
Unfortunately, passing of a C-array argument selects both candidate functions because pointer decay of the C-array must be at the same level of consideration, making the situation ambiguous.
#include <iostream>

static void foo(int* p) {
    std::cout << "int* -> " << *p << "\n";
}

static void foo(int (&a)[4]) {
    std::cout << "int[4] -> "
        << a[0] << " "
        << a[1] << " "
        << a[2] << " "
        << a[3] << "\n";
}

int main() {
    int array[4]{ 10, 20, 30, 40 };
    foo(array); // error: call to 'foo' is ambiguous
    foo(array + 3);
}

I am currently using this workaround.  I am not happy with this workaround.
static void foo(int (*a)[4]) { /*...*/ }

...which would be called via...
    foo(&array);

The alternative to change the pass-by-pointer to pass-by-reference-to-pointer void foo(int*& p) would preclude calling it by foo(array + 3) since that's an rvalue.
Is there another approach (or template magic) that could disambiguate the two situations?
Context is preferably C++17, but if a decent solution can be expressed in C++20 or later that would still be of interest.
(XY problem?) The original context was argument passing of a pointer or array as a class constructor parameter.  The original context is an attempt to make a "fat pointer", like Google's Miracle Pointer, that is a pointer drop-in replacement of a regular raw pointer yet contains span and offset information and paranoia checks (which does incur additional runtime overhead).  I've tried to simplify the example down to the salient and minimal repro case.
UPDATE (replying to comment): ultimately, I'd like it also to support and distinguish a const int[4] and a const int* as well.

(Not what you are asking for, but:) Get rid of built-in array complete and replace them all by std::array. They behave much more reasonably. In the function parameter replace int (*a)[4] with the corresponding fixed-length std::span.

If you make the pointer overload a template instead (e.g. template<typename=void>), then it will be considered a worse candidate on ambiguity.

A pointer drop-in replacement can just be a normal class type with the appropriate overloads. It does not need to rely on built-in arrays or pointers. The standard library even has a concept for such types and supports them e.g. in the allocator interface. (There are some things that can't be completely drop-in, e.g. if user code uses std::is_pointer, explicitly writes out references to built-in pointer types, etc., but you have that problem anyway.)

Is the lack of const here significant?

that would be an evil overload if were allowed

And you can't just have two differently named functions because... ???

@selbie • because the original context is in a constructor, and constructors cannot be named differently.  (And the code base in question is about 80 MLOC, with a few thousand CVEs, and targeting the raw pointers is easy because all the raw pointers are being used through typedefs like using PFoo = Foo*; so there is a single-point-of-change using PFoo = fat_ptr<Foo>; that will take care of several MLOC in one fell swoop.)

So, in your real fat_ptr the number of elements in the array is a template parameter, then?

could the array version of the constructor include the size?  that would also allow code to do boundary checks, blocking index >= size.

@IgorG • Yes, it's using a template <std::size_t N> fat_ptr(T (&a)[N]) constructor.

Dispatcher with if constexpr (std::is_array works.
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

static void fooin(int* p) {
    std::cout << "int* -> " << *p << "\n";
}

static void fooinarr(int (&a)[4]) {
    std::cout << "int[4] -> "
        << a[0] << " "
        << a[1] << " "
        << a[2] << " "
        << a[3] << "\n";
}

template<typename T>
static void foo(T &&a) {
    if constexpr (std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>) {
        fooinarr(std::forward<T>(a));
    } else {
        fooin(std::forward<T>(a));
    }
}

int main() {
    int array[4]{ 10, 20, 30, 40 };
    foo(array); // error: call to 'foo' is ambiguous
    foo(array + 3);
}

or the same:
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>, int> = 0>
static void foo(T &&a) {
        fooinarr(std::forward<T>(a));
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>, int> = 0>
static void foo(T &&a) {
        fooin(std::forward<T>(a));
}


The second part labelled "same" worked best for my actual code.  C++ templates are pretty obtuse.  Both the first suggestion and the addendum suggestion were very helpful, thank you.


Unfortunately, passing of a C-array argument selects both candidate functions

So, you should artificially make the non-array constructor worse.
The simpliest way was already offered in a comment by @user17732522.
But if for some reason that doesn't work for you, here's an older approach: introduce a user-defined conversion.
template <typename T>
struct RawPtr
{
    [[gnu::always_inline]] constexpr RawPtr(T* ptr)
     : m_ptr(ptr)
    {
    }

    T*      m_ptr;
};

template <typename T>
struct FatPtr
{
    FatPtr(RawPtr<T> p);
    
    template <size_t N>
    FatPtr(T (&p)[N]);
};

template <typename T>
FatPtr(T*) -> FatPtr<T>;

int main()
{
    int         arr[5] = {};
    const char  carr[3] = {};

    FatPtr      t1(arr);
    FatPtr      t2(arr + 3);
    FatPtr      t3(carr);
    FatPtr      t4(carr + 1);
}

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/1o9KT833x

Very useful technique.  I tried this out first because I liked the easily understood approach, but I ultimately used KamilCuk's second suggested technique.  (Also KamilCuk's answer more directly answered my question as given, but your answer was appropriate for my actual problem.)
